# Laravel guzzle cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: http (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, laravel, curl

On my development my code is working properly. When I push to my server it become error.

`cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: http (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

Here is my code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

try {
    $client = new Client();
    $client->request('POST', env('API_DOMAIN') . '/v1/user/auth/verified_email',
        ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'cm9vcGlhLnVzZXIud2ViOkY0RVN3VXJheS1qVVB1a18='],
         'query'   => ['token' => $key]]);

    return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Your email has been verified. Thanks!')->with('statusType', 'success');
} catch (ConnectException $e) {
    Log::error($e);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: have you set API_DOMAIN in your .env ?

Comment: Restart the server. After two hours that was what worked for me.

Comment: I restarted server, problem happened again.

Comment: Did u solve this problem bro?

Answer (score 14):

My solution is to clear all type of caches in Artisan.

Run these commands together:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

I spent a day to find that the best practice is to actually catch Exceptions in the following manner:

```
catch(\Exception $ex)
```

That \ makes all the difference! so DO NOT use :

```
catch(Exception $ex)
```

You can put this catch at the end where all other specific exceptions are caught.

Comment: Please, read about Namespaces, as this not about `\`, but about Namespaces you've used wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your API_DOMAIN may not have been set to a proper url (did it start with http:// or https://)?

It may also be worth a try to restart the web server (e.g. restart nginx).

It could also be a connectivity issue on your server. You can try a reboot of the VPS or check if the firewall did not block your outgoing request. Maybe disable iptables or firewalld for a moment.

There could also be issues with the DNS for the API_DOMAIN. Maybe you did configure it locally in your /etc/hosts on your developmnet environment but not on production. You may check if the dns resolves properly or add it to your /etc/hosts file on your production server.

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me. It turned out to be a disparity between curl versions on OSX. Each had a version of openssl being used. Nightmare to find but a straightforward fix.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908305/2867894

Answer (score 1):

Do

> php artisan optimize:clear

to clear all caches in laravel

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and it turns out that I was tunneling through a proxy server. I stopped routing through a proxy and it worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just run your web server, I had the same error but my server was OFF, then I turn it on, and it works for me