# cURL + Laravel Valet + dnsmasq not working

Tags: php, laravel, curl, dnsmasq, laravel-valet

when I execute a PHP script which runs a cURL request to a .test domain that is setup on my Mac with Laravel Valet/dnsmasq,  I get this error printed :

> Could not resolve: mydomain.test (Domain name not found)

When I test the domain in my browser, it's OK.
When I run `curl -Ik https://mydomain.test` in the Terminal, I get HTTP/2 200 code, so it's OK.
When I run `curl -k https://mydomain.test` in the Terminal I get the source code of the page, so it's OK.

Why is it not working with cURL from PHP ? I'm desperate...

UPDATE

Due to popular demand ;-) here is my cURL code. You cannot do more simple :

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init( "http://mydomain.test" );
    curl_exec( $ch );
    dump(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close( $ch );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your PHP curl code?

Comment: It's difficult to say something without your php curl code

Comment: I've updated with code.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688451/curl-laravel-valet-dnsmasq-not-working/54908305#54908305

Answer (score 49):

This problem is caused by curl versions, can you check your curl versions from terminal by

`curl --version` and `php --ri curl`

When you run `php --ri curl` you will see `cURL Information => 7.63.0` this line.

Then you can compare your versions and you see which curl version is not working with dnsmasq.

I encountered this problem and my curl version was 7.64.0 in php.

---

**For solve that issue:**

You can uninstall *curl-openssl*, this command will remove last version of curl-openssl:

```
brew uninstall curl-openssl --ignore-dependencies
```

Then restart php:

```
brew services restart php
```

After restarting, php will see curl which is `/usr/bin/curl` and this version can access local domain.

Comment: I've uninstall curl-openssl (which was 7.64) and it still does not work with the other curl which is 7.54. I restarted valet and php.

Comment: Worked out for me. Should be the accepted answer ! Thanks a lot mate !

Comment: needed valet restart as stated by Leo Moraes's answer, and it works great

Comment: I was looking for solution for days. brew uninstall curl-openssl --ignore-dependencies is worked for me. thank yo very much

Comment: Unfortunately, Apache would not start anymore: `httpd: Syntax error on line 194 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so, 10): Symbol not found: _curl_mime_addpart\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib\n in /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`

Comment: Apache also wont start for me. Same error as above. So this answer fixes one issue but introduces another, at least on PHP 7.3

Answer (score 7):

....After restarting, php will see curl which is /usr/bin/curl and this version can access local domain.

After restarting too the valet: *valet restart*

Answer (score 5):

Adding `127.0.0.1` to my DNS settings fixed this issue for me.
i.e. `System Preferences -> Network -> Advance -> DNS`

And Run `valet restart` afterwards

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding `domain.test` to `/etc/hosts`

i.e., in the hosts file add: `127.0.0.1 domain.test`

Answer (score 2):

Just spent the last hour on this. I had a similar problem with curl through PHP not resolving with Valet specially for SSL. I tried changing curl-openssl versions and also setting my domain in the host file etc. Nothing worked apart from the following:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

This is due to the valet SSL not being verified by Curl. Once I added this option to my curl request I was able to fetch data from my local valet url.

Comment: No clue why this was downvoted. The widely-accepted answers above make no case for causation, while this answer feels like it's far closer to doing so (although it didn't work for me).

Comment: You probably saved me a few hours with this reply. Thank you!